# simplified regex for modifying a string in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

Here is my original string:

```
"Chassis ID TLV\n\tMAC: 00:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx\nPort ID TLV\n\tIfname: Ethernet1/3\nTime to Live TLV\n\t120"
```

and i want the string to be formatted as :

```
"Chassis ID TLV;00:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx\nPort ID TLV;Ethernet1/3\nTime to Live TLV;120"
```

so i used following ruby string functions to do it:

```
y = x.gsub(/\t[a-zA-Z\d]+:/,"\t")
y = y.gsub(/\t /,"\t")
y = y.gsub("\n\t",";")
```

so i am looking for a one liner to do the above. since i am not used to regex, i tried doing it sequentially. i am messing it up when i try to do all of them together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace the following construct

```
[\n\r]\t(?:\w+: )?
```

with `;`, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/rohcFA/1).

Answer (score 4):

I'd tackle it as a few smaller steps:

```
input = "Chassis ID TLV\n\tMAC: 00:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx\nPort ID TLV\n\tIfname: Ethernet1/3\nTime to Live TLV\n\t120"
input.split(/\n\t?/).map { |s| s.sub(/\A[^:]+\:\s*/, '') }.join(';')
# => "Chassis ID TLV;00:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx;Port ID TLV;Ethernet1/3;Time to Live TLV;120"
```

That way you have control over each element instead of being entirely dependent on the regular expression to do it as one shot.